# Efficient available time finder

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a set of appointments on a specific work day that goes from 8am to 6pm:

Appointment 1: 9am-11am
Appointment 2: 2pm-5pm

I am looking for an efficient way to locate the free time.  So in this case, the available time would be:

8am-9am
11am-2pm
5pm-6pm

So I have an TimeBlock class

```
class TimeBlock {
  public DateTime start
  public DateTime end
}

var appointments = new List<TimeBlock>();
var freeTimeBlocks = new List<TimeBlock>();

' add appointments
appointments.Add(new TimeBlock{start...
appointments.Add(new TimeBlock{start...
```

I am looking for an efficient way to find free time, because the algorithm will run on a pretty big data set.

Comment: How will it work when there is more than one day? Will it consider different days separately? I imagine so because presumably you would not want to have the middle of the night considered available time!

Comment: What output do you need? A list of available ranges?

Comment: @Robin Green - for the time being I am concerned about a single day.  The work day only goes from 8am to 6pm, so I don't have to worry about cross-midnight scenarios.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes, the output is list of available ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it assumes there's no overlapping appointments:

```
var orderedAppointments = appointments.OrderBy(a => a.start).ToArray();

freeTimeBlocks.Clear();

for(int i = 0; i < orderedAppointments.Length - 1; i++)
{
    freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock(){ start = orderedAppointments[i].end; end = orderedAppointments[i + 1].start });
}
var firstAppointment = orderedAppointments.First();
var lastAppointment = orderedAppointments.Last();

if(firstAppointment.start.Hour > 8)
   freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock() { start = firstAppointment.Today.AddHours(8); end = firstAppointment.start });
if(lastAppointment.end.Hour < 18)
   freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock() { start = lastAppointment.end; end = lastAppointment.Today.AddHours(18) });
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the timeblocks are sorted (`O(nlogn)`, or better), then loop through them and create availability ranges from the end of each block to the beginning of the next (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach would be asymptotically very efficient for huge data sets (d*u >> n), as long as they can fit in memory:

If the number of days is d, the number of users is u and the average number of appointments per user per day is n, this is O(d*u*n), whereas a sorting-based individual day approach would be more like O(d*u*n*log n).

(If u=1 or d=1, it doesn't matter - it makes no difference.)

1. Create an array of lists indexed by all the
   possible time slots. For example if
   you can have time slots every 5
   minutes, you would have an array of
   size 120. This step is O(1). We assume that the number of possible time slots is fixed, and it should therefore have no bearing on the complexity analysis.
2. Loop through *all* the appointments, for *all* days and *all* users, and add the appointments (together with a record of for which user and day it is) to the corresponding list for *both* the appointment start and the appointment end times. This step is O(d*u*n), if you use a linked list and add them at the head of the list each time.
3. Create an array to record the "current" free time slot for each day and user - you'll see how this works in the next step.
4. Loop through the first array, and for each list in the array, loop through that list (so, the loops are nested). For each appointment you see that is an "end appointment now", start recording a new free time slot at that time, for that day and user. For each appointment you see that is a "start appointment now", finish recording the free time slot for that day and user, if any, and discard it if it is zero-duration - if there is not one and it's not 8am, create one. This step is also O(d*u*n).
5. Finish up any open free time records at 6pm. This step is worst case O(d*u).

No inter-appointment comparisons or searches needed!

This is based on radix sort.

However, I am not sure whether this will be better *in practice*. It certainly requires more space!

Answer (score 1):

Could be as easy as this, provided you don't have any overlapping appointments (from your problem statement that shouldn't be possible):

```
appointments.Sort((a,b) => a.Start.CompareTo(b.Start));
for(int i = 0; i< appointments.Count-1; i++)
{
    if(appointments[i].End < appointments[i+1].Start)
        freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock() { Start  = appointments[i].End, End = appointments[i+1].Start });
}
```

This doesn't account for the edge cases of time before the first appointment and after the last one, those you would have to manually check for and add.

Answer (score 1):

This answer also works with the assumption that there would be no overlapping appointments. Instead of working with the 8AM - 6PM time frame given in the question, this solution allows for one or more available time periods to be set.

I think this can be made more elegant but I can't figure out how to get that done.

```
private static List<TimeBlock> GetDayOpenSlots(IEnumerable<TimeBlock> daySlots,
    IReadOnlyCollection<TimeBlock> usedDaySlots)
{
    var freeTimeBlocks = new List<TimeBlock>();
    foreach (var daySlot in daySlots)
    {
        var selectedSlotsWithinRange = usedDaySlots
            .Where(x => x.StartTime >= daySlot.StartTime && x.EndTime <= daySlot.EndTime)
            .OrderBy(x => x.StartTime)
            .ToList();

        if (!selectedSlotsWithinRange.Any())
        {
            freeTimeBlocks.Add(daySlot);
            continue;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSlotsWithinRange.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var currentSlot = selectedSlotsWithinRange[i];
            var nextSlot = selectedSlotsWithinRange[i + 1];
            if (currentSlot.EndTime == nextSlot.StartTime)
            {
                continue;
            }

            freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock(currentSlot.EndTime,
                nextSlot.StartTime));
        }

        var firstAppointment = selectedSlotsWithinRange.First();
        var lastAppointment = selectedSlotsWithinRange.Last();

        if (firstAppointment.StartTime > daySlot.StartTime)
        {
            freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock(daySlot.StartTime,
                firstAppointment.StartTime));
        }

        if (lastAppointment.EndTime < daySlot.EndTime)
        {
            freeTimeBlocks.Add(new TimeBlock(lastAppointment.EndTime, daySlot.EndTime));
        }
    }

    return freeTimeBlocks
        .OrderBy(x => x.StartTime)
        .ToList();
}
```